# How to interact with a fresh raspberry without pluging any screen ? (network config on Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, dhcp

I already know how to enable SSH : you have to drop a "ssh" file on the boot partition on the MicroSD card.

What I don't know, is how to get an IP for my raspberry. In /etc/network/interfaces, the default raspbian settings is all on "manual" :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Do I have to plug a screen and a keyboard only to change "manual" to "dhcp" on the "iface eth0" line ?

Would NOOBS help for this ?

Comment: By default the pi can be reached with the hostname raspberrypi.local this does require that bonjour is running (on a PC itunes will provide this). Another option is to check your router for connected devices and the cooresponding IP address. IIRC manual here has the oposite meaning as you would expect. This thread  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=110606 discusses manual vs dhcp.

Comment: My problem is my Pi is not getting any valid IP address until I change "manual" to "dhcp" in /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You "get" an IP address from your router (or other network element) providing your DHCP server.

Without knowing details of your network, it is difficult to be more specific.

If you are connected to the Pi `ifconfig` will show the address.

In most cases you **do not need** to know the IP address. `raspberrypi.local` can be used in lieu of IP in most cases (certain uncommon Windows networks excepted).

Comment: My problem is my Pi is not getting any valid IP address until I change "manual" to "dhcp" in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Unless you have modified something Raspbian will get an IP by default. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Likewise, I've never seen a raspberry pi fail to get an IP via DHCP (assuming the link is up)
Is this Wifi or LAN?

Comment: This is hard to decode information for a noob like me : are u saying DHCP is used wether u put "manual" or "dhcp" in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: The `manual` just indicates that network setting, whether by DHCP or another mechanism, is performed by an external procedure. If you put `dhcp` into `/etc/network/interfaces` this disables the default Network Manager `dhcpcd`. The default is **far** more robust than the older Debian networking. (Just for the record there are a number of other Network Managers which work well, just the Foundation has integrated `dhcpcd`.) `/etc/network/interfaces` is an anachronism, and is unnecessary; if you delete it the Pi will work, although you need to include the wireless hook, omitted by Raspbian.